# How can you export content from your Output in VS Code?

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code, azure-eventhub

I am utilizing an extension called Azure Event Hub Explorer in Visual Studio Code. The extension allows me to see messages from an Azure Event Hub within the VS Code Output.

There are a lot of messages and you have to scroll through them to find what you want. There is no way to filter the results. I am looking for a way to export the output into something like a **csv** file so that I can easily filter my results.

Please let me know if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Open log file" button on right upper corner of output window. Also you can canfigure key bindings for commands:

[image]